# How to style scrollbar same as ie scrollar

Tags: html, css

> I want to style a scrollbar in a webapp I'm working on with the same
>   style as in the horizontal scrollbar in the image link below.  How can
>   I do this?

[ie scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E34IN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall answer your question and yes it work in safari . I am not gonna type all just look at
 **https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

Edit the scroll bar as you like with css.**

Comment: Thanks but I'm referring to the exact styling of the scrollbar. The scrollbar works, but it doesn't match whats in the image above.  It uses safari scrollbar style by default.